# How do I output to separate files within a batch script while preserving my path?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have a bunch of SYSTEM hives nested within folders named after the host they were taken from. I'd like to have each iteration output to separate text files, and have them named after the folder they were parsed from. So if I have:

host1\SYSTEM.hve
host2\SYSTEM.hve

I'd like my output to be:

host1.txt
host2.txt

Here is my current script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

FOR /R C:\Users\svc\Desktop\batchtest %%G in (SYSTEM) DO C:\Users\svc\Downloads\ShimCacheParser-master\ShimCacheParser-master\ShimCacheParser.py -i %%G -o C:\Users\svc\Desktop\batchtest\output.txt
```

As of right now, this batch script just overwrites the same text file on each iteration.Thanks!

Comment: I don't get what you want exactly. Do you mean something like this: `-o "%%~dpG\output.txt"`? Perhaps it helped if you would show some sample data...

Comment: So I have the following structure:
folder1\file
folder2\file
folder3\file

What I want is to parse each file with the script, but also retain the path in the output name: folder1_file.txt, folder2_file.txt etc...The issue is that the file name is the same within each folder.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put the extra info there!

Comment: I reformatted the question, hope this helps!